# convert time to utc in Dune Query

Tags: ethereumj, defi, query, dune

I can create a query on the DuneAnalytics site, but the default date format for a field is "2022-02-08 02:44", which downloads to csv as "2022-02-08T02:44:46+00:00". Does anyone know the code for translating this time field into UTC seconds (eg, 1627834020)?

Below is a query that works on the Ethereum chain at dune.xyz

```
SELECT 
    "evt_block_time",
    "evt_block_number"
    FROM uniswap_v3."Pair_evt_Swap"
    WHERE contract_address = '\x88e6a0c2ddd26feeb64f039a2c41296fcb3f5640'
      and "evt_block_number" = 14162840
```